# EF Generated MetaData and IE8 (Getters and Setters can not be defined on this javascript engine)

Tags: breeze

Using IE8 (Everything works fine IE9+)
Im using EF to generate the metadata as outlined in the "EF Design Tool" document 
I've added ES5 Shim/Sham 
Breeze appears to be loading fine

Once I load the meta data I get the following error
"Unable to either parse or import metadata: getters and setters can not be defined on this javascript engine"

Is this something I can work around?

At this stage its just a prototype and Im only using one trivial class (Below)

```
public class Category
{
   private Guid catId;

    [Key]
    public Guid CatID
    {
        get { return catId; }
        set { catId = value; }
    }

    private string catDesc;

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CatDesc
    {   
        get { return catDesc; }
        set { catDesc = value; }
    }

    public Category()
    {
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is described in the breezeJs documentation here: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/prerequisites - the relevant section is excerpted below:

> Note: Because of IE8 and shim limitations having to do with Object.defineProperty, the breeze 
>   'backingStore' model library is not supported under IE8, however, the 'knockout' and 'backbone' 
>    libraries are supported.

Answer (score 0):

To use breeze and IE8 you have to have knockout or backbone as the backing store.  The default breeze backing store uses Object.defineProperty which only works on IE8 DOM objects.